# Machine swapping with cached memory

Tags: memory-management, centos7

Why is my server swapping even if there is enough memory as cached ?

The machine is running a CentOS 7 and is equipped with:

 - **755 GB** of RAM

 - **32 GB** Swap

The swappiness is set to 1

This is the meminfo:

```
MemTotal:       792087296 kB
MemFree:         4465804 kB
MemAvailable:   224683056 kB
Buffers:              24 kB
Cached:         216998152 kB
SwapCached:     17792052 kB
Active:         672773100 kB
Inactive:       104668396 kB
Active(anon):   519239536 kB
Inactive(anon): 41416180 kB
Active(file):   153533564 kB
Inactive(file): 63252216 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      33554428 kB
SwapFree:         398388 kB
Dirty:               364 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      542653804 kB
Mapped:            50276 kB
Shmem:            212980 kB
Slab:            3968696 kB
SReclaimable:    3769332 kB
SUnreclaim:       199364 kB
KernelStack:       18512 kB
PageTables:      1146652 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    429598076 kB
Committed_AS:   580019976 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:     1885084 kB
VmallocChunk:   33948891128 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:  264464384 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      313660 kB
DirectMap2M:    63309824 kB
DirectMap1G:    741343232 kB
```

Any clue?

EDIT, Some more background informations:

The machine is mainly a mysql server which hosts around 8TB of data and it is a slave (for only read purposes) in a simple master-slave replication setup.
The memory is mainly cached or used by mysqld, there is nothing else of importance that may use significative amount of resources.

Comment: This would be better asked over on [su] or [sf] as its not strictly a programming issue and thus off-topic here. You also give no details on the system, what it's work-load is or anything that may lead people to be able to assist.

Comment: background is not relevant here, as the only process with a significative resource usage is mysqld. I've put this question on Super User as well, haven't received an answer yet. Trying to hear any smart intuition here, as Stack has a bit more visibility compared to the other networks sites. Ty for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the "Why", but two things you could try:

1- Set swappiness to zero.

2- Disable swapping altogether.

There's a good reference on it [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/684771/best-way-to-disable-swap-in-linux), but the highlights are:

1. Identify configured swap devices and files with **cat /proc/swaps**.
2. Turn off all swap devices and files with **swapoff -a**.
3. Remove any matching reference found in **/etc/fstab**.

One other note, even with swapping disabled, you can sometimes see pages freed and paged in.  Executables are generally memory-mapped.  The kernel knows that it can restore those code pages from disk if needed, so it can free them with impunity, in order to free up RAM for cache or other purposes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was afraid about setting up swappiness to 0 because my though was that this will prevent the machine from swapping at all, which means a very very bad scenario in case of memory leaking cases, but i will explore it. Unfortunately i can't set up a testing environment with that amount of resources but will try it in a smaller scale.

Comment: You're welcome.  Be sure to post back about your results/update.